# How to copy a file in a folder 2 level up where the shell file is being run on OSX?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

The shell script is run from `Parent/SubfolderA/SubfolderB/`

The target directory is `Parent`

What is the correct path way to use with `cp` command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

using relative path

`cp file  ../../`

or

using absolute path

`cp file  Parent/`  here parent is the full path to parent directory

Comment: Thank you, now what to do when I get Permission Denied?

Comment: try `sudo cp file  ../../`   or login as root.
you can even provide privileges on that directory by `chmod`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to parent directory using the cmd `cd parent`
2. `sudo cp -a SubfolderA/SubfolderB/file .` to copy the file and its permission as well. Using `sudo` would get temporary root permission for this command, so that you would not encounter "permission denied".